# Android dependency version inside ext vs dependencies block

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Where do we declare *Android* dependencies versions in a project?
Should the versions be defined in the project level `ex{ }` block

[image: top-level android build script]

or the module level `dependencies { }` block?

[image: android module-level build script]

Answer (score 1):

> Where do we declare *Android* dependencies versions in a project?

In brief,

- for a multi-module project (`app` module etc.) use project's *build.gradle*,
- for a single-module project (`app` module only) use `app`'s *build.gradle*

When following the rule for a multi-module project, a library's version change is done only in one place and effects all the dependent modules.

Consider the following example with the *Kotlin* library version.

In project's *build.gradle*:

```
ext {
    kotlin_version = '1.4.21'
    ...
    kotlin_stdlib = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

In a module's (e.g. `app`'s) *build.gradle*:

```
dependencies {
    implementation kotlin_stdlib
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

build.gradle - project module with at the bottom

```
ext.dependenciesVersion = [:]
dependenciesVersion.libraryName = "x.x.x"
```

build.gradle - app module

```
implementation "librarySource.$dependencyVersion.libraryName"
```